# How to show a message when focus on a view in android app

Tags: android

[image: Just like as when we bring the cursor on icon it shows settings message as infollowing image]

my code is......

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.user.designingapp.CapCustomize">
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigate"
    android:orderInCategory="300"
    android:title="User"
    android:icon="@drawable/back"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/share"
    android:orderInCategory="300"
    android:title="Use"
    android:icon="@drawable/share"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

I want that when i bring the cursor on these two item's image .there should show a message as name of items just like in the above image...

Comment: on long pressed it will automatically show the messge

Comment: Thanks to help me....

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) in android to achieve this. [Here is an example](http://android-er.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html).

If you want it to look like the menu items or want to use the menu xml, you can use [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) which also have a [v7 compatibility version](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html). [Example](http://javatechig.com/android/android-popup-menu-example).

Also, if this is a button or image and you only want to show popup text as help or as a hint, there is a `contentDescription` attribute in which you can specify the text, which will show on long press.

Comment: No thanks needed, you just need to mark the answer as the correct one.